# AWS CDK: Stopping spot instances in EC2 fleet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

I'm new to AWS CDK and I want to achieve these requirements:

- launching 4 ec2 instances
- instance type = spot
- I want to start/stop the spot instances every day, no termination of these instances

I've tried to launch an EC2 fleet for this scenario and configured "stop" as value for interruption behaviour and "persistent" as spot instance type.
Launching these instances works fine, but when I try to stop an instance I receive this error:

```
You can't stop the Spot Instance 'xyz' because it is in a fleet, which does not support stop.
```

As far as I understand the documentation of class EC2.Instance launching spot instances currently are not supported, so this is no workaround for me.

1. Did I forget to configure anything in my EC2 fleet or launch template?
2. Do you have any other ideas to meet my requirements?

Thanks a lot!

### Relevant parts of my code

EC2 Fleet launch template:

```
ec2.CfnLaunchTemplate.LaunchTemplateDataProperty(
                    instance_type="r5.xlarge", 
                    instance_market_options=
                        ec2.CfnLaunchTemplate.InstanceMarketOptionsProperty(
                        market_type="spot",
                        spot_options=(
                                ec2.CfnLaunchTemplate.SpotOptionsProperty(
                                    instance_interruption_behavior="stop",
                                    spot_instance_type="persistent"
                                )
                        )
                    )
```

EC2 Fleet:

```
            target_capacity_specification=
                ec2.CfnEC2Fleet.TargetCapacitySpecificationRequestProperty(
                    default_target_capacity_type="spot",
                    total_target_capacity=1,
                    spot_target_capacity=1
                ),
            spot_options=
                ec2.CfnEC2Fleet.SpotOptionsRequestProperty(
                    max_total_price="3.600",
                    instance_interruption_behavior="stop"
            )
```

Comment: Check these answers: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52201821/can-i-stop-a-spot-instance-in-aws-just-like-i-can-stop-and-start-an-on-demand-ec
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59730890/stopping-spot-instance-temporarily